# Quote Torah verses only in full?

Tags: tanach

Over the years I read in many places that a Torah verse must be quoted only in full, not partially.  Is this true?  What is the source?  At any rate, wasn't the division of the Torah in verses done by non-Jews?  Would this not tend to invalidate the teaching (if true)?

Comment: The division into verses was done by Jews! The te'amim indicate verse endings (by a siluq).

Comment: https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=62542

Comment: It would indeed tend to invalidate the teaching if true.

Comment: I believe the Talmud is the source that quoting Tanakh must be done as a full verse. The division of the Torah into verses was done by Jews first via the te'amim, but we didn't create verse and chapter numbers, that was done by Christians. And this rule of quoting the whole verse is why some people do not begin kiddush with "YomHaShishi." Not only is the original custom and law to begin with Va-yekhulu, the adding of yom shishi is very late, kabbalistic in nature, AND violates the rule of only quoting whole verses

Comment: If reciting it by heart, partial quoting is arguably preferable. See the Rebbe's note at the bottom [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58872&st=&pgnum=23).

Comment: @Aaron, following my father's practice, I say the whole preceding passuk